# $RG\otimes_{RP}RL\simeq RGe_U$, when $P=LU$ is a parabolic subgroup of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules, representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Suppose $G$ is an algebraic group, $P=LU$ is a parabolic subgroup with Levi factor and unipotent subgroup $L$ and $U$, respectively. Let $R$ is a commutative, unital ring and $e_U=\frac{1}{|U|}\sum_{u\in U}u$, so I'm assuming $R$ has characteristic such that $|U|^{-1}$ makes sense.

> Why are $RG\otimes_{RP} RL$ and $RGe_U$ isomorphic as $(RG,RL)$-bimodules?

The map $RG\times RL\to RGe_U$ sending $(x,y)\mapsto xye_U$ is $RP$-bilinear, and clearly surjective, so it induces a surjection $RG\otimes_{RP}RL\to RGe_U$ via $x\otimes y\mapsto xye_U$, but I'm not sure if it's injective. That it's a map of left $RG$-modules seems okay, but since $RG\otimes_{RP}RL$ is a right $RL$-module by multiplication, this would require $xye_U\ell=xy\ell e_U$, for $\ell\in RL$, which doesn't seem quite right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Levi decomposition $P=L\ltimes U$, $L$ normalizes $U$, so $\ell U=U\ell$, and hence $\ell$ commutes with the idempotent $e_U$. So the equation $xye_U\ell=xy\ell e_U$ does hold.